# HTTP500: server error!! ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I am getting an error in my IE developer tools:

> HTTP500: SERVER ERROR - The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.
>   (XHR): GET - http://127.0.0.1:3000/calendars/calendar_change?colleagueID=3

My terminal is displaying this error:

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 158ms

ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass):
    1: alert("<%= @colleague.id %>")
  app/views/calendars/calendar_change.js.erb:1:in `_app_views_calendars_calendar_change_js_erb__940402316_55367244'
```

The error reports that `@colleague` is nil, but I don't understand how this could be. Here is some background to what I am doing:

I have defined a view `events\new.html.erb` which contains a form with a `collection_select`, allowing a customer to select another customer (deemed a 'colleague'):

```
#events\new.html.erb
<%= f.collection_select :id,
      Customer.where(business_id: current_customer.business_id),
      :id,
      :full_name,
      { prompt: 'Select' },
      { id: "colleageselect", onChange: "renderColCal(this)" } 
%>
```

This executes the Javascript function that collects the customer value selected:

```
function renderColCal(select){

    var colleagueID = select.value ;
    $.ajax({
            url: 'calendars/calendar_change',
            data:{
                colleagueID: $('select').val()
            }
        }
    )
}
```

which gets sent to the `calendars_controller\calendar_change` action:

```
def calendar_change
    colleagueID = params[:colleagueID] #is this correct? 


    @colleague = Customer.find(colleagueID) #@colleague is showing up as 'nil'
    @colcalendar = @colleague.calendar
    @events = @colleague.calendar.events

 end
```

Here is my calendar_change view at the moment (I'm just trying to stop the server error using simple alerts before actually implementing any real stuff):

```
#calendars\calendar_change.js.erb

alert("<%= @colleague.id %>")
```

So why is my `@colleague` variable created in Ruby showing up as `nil`?? I would appreciate a bit of help.

Comment: Hey, check what is being sent from the browser as parameters in the Ajax request. That will give you an insight as to what key you have to use to get the `colleagueID` . (you could`puts params.inspect` in the controller action to see the contents of the hash)

Comment: It seems to be sending the correct ID number: Started GET "/calendars/calendar_change?colleagueID=3" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-01-22 07:39:08 +0000
Processing by CalendarsController#calendar_change as */*
  Parameters: {"colleagueID"=>"3"}

Answer (score 0):

The `$('select')` expression returns a collection of DOM elements and not a single `<select>` element. This means that the expression `$('select').val()` does not return the ID but `undefined`.

You do not need the `$('select').val()` as you have already stored the value in `colleagueID`. You'll need to refactor your code like so:

```
function renderColCal(select){

    var colleagueID = select.value ;
    $.ajax({
        url: 'calendars/calendar_change',
        data:{
            colleagueID: colleagueID
        }
    });
}
```